# I want to access multiple domains using one moodle mobile app. is it possible to handle multiple? domains with one app in moodle

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

I am using moodle 3.2.1 version and i have 3 subdomains. I want to access these domains using one moodle mobile app. is it possible to handle multiple domains with one app in moodle ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to access multiple domains from one moodle mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that, you just need to customize the form where users put the URL, with your list of URLs. This way your users won't be prompted to enter a URL everytime they open your app. They get a list of websites or platforms that they can log in to by clicking or choosing from a drop-down menu or whatever you are planning to do.

This is the [controller](https://github.com/moodlehq/moodlemobile2/blob/master/www/core/components/login/controllers/site.js) of the page where users enter the URL. Bind the siteurl field with the custom control you are going to use in the view.

In the controller view, you can customize the selection as it suits you. You can find the view under templates of the same parent folder (or check it [here](https://github.com/moodlehq/moodlemobile2/blob/master/www/core/components/login/templates/site.html)).

But you must give intention when you try to update your code with changes from the upstream (official repository).